# Change a Stored Procedure - Cursor MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wanted to know if this is possible to do in SQL Server, to do it in another way than cursors because its extremly slow. Have a Cursor that checks the row prior to itself and IF @Machine <> @MachineCur OR @MachineStatus <> @MachinestatusCur OR @sShift <> @sShiftCur then do a insert into a table.

CODE:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON

    GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[MSTATE] @STARTDATE AS DATE, @ENDDATE AS DATE AS

    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @LINE AS VARCHAR(255), @MACHINE AS VARCHAR(255), @OBJECTTYPE AS VARCHAR(15), @INV AS VARCHAR(9), @MACHINESTATUS AS VARCHAR(255), @TIMESTART AS DATETIME, @TIMEEND AS DATETIME, @SSHIFT AS VARCHAR(100), @LINECUR AS VARCHAR(255), @MACHINECUR AS VARCHAR(255), @OBJECTTYPECUR AS VARCHAR(15), @INVCUR AS VARCHAR(9), @MACHINESTATUSCUR AS VARCHAR(255), @TIMESTARTCUR AS DATETIME, @TIMEENDCUR AS DATETIME, @SSHIFTCUR AS VARCHAR(100), @FIRST AS BIT

    IF @STARTDATE IS NULL SET @STARTDATE = '2015-01-01'
    IF @ENDDATE IS NULL SET @ENDDATE = GETDATE()

    TRUNCATE TABLE [DBO].[MSTATETEMP]

    DECLARE CUR10 CURSOR FOR

    SELECT [LINE],[MACHINE],[OBJECTTYPE],[INV],[MACHINESTATUS],[TIMESTART],[TIMEEND],[SSHIFT] FROM [DBO].[OEEQSTATEDATAPREVIEW] WHERE TIMESTART >= @STARTDATE AND TIMEEND <= @ENDDATE ORDER BY MACHINE, TIMESTART


    SET @FIRST = 0

        OPEN CUR10
                FETCH NEXT FROM CUR10 INTO @LINE, @MACHINE, @OBJECTTYPE, @INV, @MACHINESTATUS, @TIMESTART, @TIMEEND, @SSHIFT
            WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN

            IF @FIRST = 0   BEGIN

                                SET @LINECUR = @LINE
                                SET @MACHINECUR = @MACHINE
                                SET @OBJECTTYPECUR = @OBJECTTYPE 
                                SET @INVCUR = @INV
                                SET @MACHINESTATUSCUR = @MACHINESTATUS
                                SET @TIMESTARTCUR = @TIMESTART
                                SET @TIMEENDCUR = @TIMEEND 
                                SET @SSHIFTCUR = @SSHIFT
                                SET @FIRST = 1
                            END     

            IF @MACHINE <> @MACHINECUR OR @MACHINESTATUS <> @MACHINESTATUSCUR OR @SSHIFT <> @SSHIFTCUR
                        BEGIN   
                                INSERT INTO [DBO].[MSTATETEMP] (LINE, MACHINE, OBJECTTYPE, INV, MACHINESTATUS, TIMESTART, TIMEEND, SSHIFT) 
                                VALUES(@LINECUR, @MACHINECUR, @OBJECTTYPECUR, @INVCUR, @MACHINESTATUSCUR, @TIMESTARTCUR, @TIMESTART, @SSHIFTCUR)
                                SET @LINECUR = @LINE
                                SET @MACHINECUR = @MACHINE
                                SET @OBJECTTYPECUR = @OBJECTTYPE 
                                SET @INVCUR = @INV
                                SET @MACHINESTATUSCUR = @MACHINESTATUS
                                SET @TIMESTARTCUR = @TIMESTART
                                SET @TIMEENDCUR = @TIMEEND 
                                SET @SSHIFTCUR = @SSHIFT
                        END
            FETCH NEXT FROM CUR10 INTO @LINE, @MACHINE, @OBJECTTYPE, @INV, @MACHINESTATUS, @TIMESTART, @TIMEEND, @SSHIFT
        END
        CLOSE CUR10
        DEALLOCATE CUR10

        SELECT LINE, MACHINE, OBJECTTYPE, INV, MACHINESTATUS, TIMESTART, TIMEEND, SSHIFT FROM [DBO].[MSTATETEMP] ORDER BY MACHINE, TIMESTART

    END
```

Result of [DBO].[OEEQSTATEDATAPREVIEW] (The inserted row will be 1 and 3):

```
Line    Machine OBJECTTYPE  INV         MACHINESTATUS   TIMESTART               TIMEEND                 SSHIFT
410     410     Linje       Invald      limit kapacitet 2015-11-06 17:00:00.000 2015-11-06 17:10:00.000 Night
410     410     Linje       Invald      limit kapacitet 2015-11-06 17:20:00.000 2015-11-06 17:30:00.000 Night
410     410     Linje       Ej invald   Avstalld        2015-11-06 19:21:01.000 2015-11-06 19:21:04.000 Night
```

Comment: Looks like you can basically just insert based on your select by joining the view and the table

Comment: Avoid looping mechanisms. Here you can write just a select query with where condition that you mentioned in IF statement and insert it.

Comment: The thing is that every row in source need to check its above row if the IF criteria match or not (if not then insert). Need help how I should handle that senario with out a cursor.

Comment: Could you show me the `[DBO].[OEEQSTATEDATAPREVIEW] ` columns? It 's sound like you do not have to have duplicated values for specific columns - insert only the unique combinations.

Comment: The OEEQSTATEDATAPREVIEW is a view, have put the result in the code  section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CTE to create unique row identifiers, then you can do a simple select

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Machine,TimeStart,TimeEnd) AS RowNum
        ,*
    FROM DBO.OEEQSTATEDATAPREVIEW
)
INSERT INTO MSTATETEMP
(Line,Machine,OBJECTTYPE,INV,MACHINESTATUS,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,SSHIFT)
SELECT Line,Machine,OBJECTTYPE,INV,MACHINESTATUS,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,SSHIFT
FROM CTE AS C
WHERE C.RowNum = 1
    OR EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM CTE AS _C
        WHERE C.RowNum = _C.RowNum + 1
            AND (C.Machine <> _C.Machine OR C.MACHINESTATUS <> _C.MACHINESTATUS OR C.SSHIFT <> _C.SSHIFT)
    )
    ;
```

Comment: first am not good at CTE, tried the one above but after 7 hours and no inserted row I stopped it. did i do anything wrong or is it so slow?